# Calculating the depth in a general stereo vision system

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

When calculating the depth of a pixel using two cameras, most of the literature I have read describes stereo vision with the cameras having parallel optical axis as shown in the picture below. Because of similar triangles, the depth Z can be calculated as

Z = (f * B) / (x_l - x_r)
[image]

What if the cameras are rotated as in the following picture? How can I calculate the depth then?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete mathematics for this are a bit tricky, as they work in 4D space, with homography projections.

In a practical sense, you can use the following functions from OpenCV library:

- `stereoCalibrate()` to calculate calibration matrices for both cameras, as well as the relationship between them.
- `stereoRectify()` to convert the images, using the data calculated with `stereoCalibrate()`, into an equivalent pair of images but with the configuration shown in your first picture. From that you can easily triangulate points position.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6

OpenCV also provides for functions to directly convert to 3D any pair of 3D points, given a calibrated system.

Finally, there are lots of nice tutorials explaining the complete pipeline for stereo reconstruction, like this one I found with a bit of googling:

https://temugeb.github.io/opencv/python/2021/02/02/stereo-camera-calibration-and-triangulation.html